# Income Transactions from Netsuite SOAP API

Tags: python, soap, netsuite

I am pulling all the transactions from Netsuite using the following SOAP Request Boby. In this body, I pass the date range and this returns me all the transactions between those two dates. But the issue is that this does not return the income transactions and I have spent around 1 week trying to figure this out. Does anyone know what may be missing here?

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

      <soap-env:Header>

          <tokenPassport >

              <account xmlns:ns1="urn:core_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">{account_id}</account>

              <consumerKey xmlns:ns2="urn:core_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">{consumer_key}</consumerKey>

              <token xmlns:ns3="urn:core_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">{token_id}</token>

              <nonce xmlns:ns4="urn:core_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">{nonce}</nonce>

              <timestamp xmlns:ns5="urn:core_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">{timestamp}</timestamp>

              <signature xmlns:ns6="urn:core_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" algorithm="HMAC-SHA256">{signature}</signature>

          </tokenPassport>

          <searchPreferences>

          <bodyFieldsOnly>false</bodyFieldsOnly>

          <pageSize>1000</pageSize>

         </searchPreferences>      

      </soap-env:Header>

        <soap-env:Body>

              <search>

                  <searchRecord xsi:type="ns8:TransactionSearch"

                      xmlns:ns8="urn:sales_2020_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com"

                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

                      <ns8:basic xsi:type="ns2:TransactionSearchBasic"

                          xmlns:ns2="urn:common_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">

                          <ns2:tranDate operator="within" xsi:type="ns3:SearchDateField"

                              xmlns:ns3="urn:core_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">

                              <ns3:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">{start_date}</ns3:searchValue>

                              <ns3:searchValue2 xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">{end_date}</ns3:searchValue2>

                          </ns2:tranDate>

                          <memorized>

                            <searchValue>false</searchValue>

                            </memorized>

                      </ns8:basic>

                  </searchRecord>

              </search>

          </soap-env:Body>

    </soap-env:Envelope>
```

Following are the permissions in the role:
[image]

I am not looking for a straight-forward answer, so if you can even guide me to any documentation, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Just to clarify when you write 'income transactions' do you mean sales transactions like invoice and cash sale? And are those permissions for the role of the token you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The search is pretty simple so the likely culprit is that the login role you are doing the search as doesn't have access to those transactions.

Failing that (based on your edited question) are you running into the 1000 row limit?

Try limiting your search to only invoices e.g after `</memorized>`

```xml
<ns2:status operator="anyOf" xsi:type="ns3:SearchEnumMultiSelectField">
    <ns3:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_invoiceOpen</ns3:searchValue>
</ns2:status>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. Do you have any idea what kind of permission is needed in the role? I have updated my question with a screenshot of currently added permissions.